# Angular RxJS - Unsubscribe from mergeMap?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

Following the best practices as described in this Stack Overflow post: [Angular RxJS When Should I Unsubscribe From Subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription), consider this Angular component lifecycle hook:

```
private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  this.fireAuth.authState
    .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    .mergeMap((user) => this.todoService.getUserTodos(user.uid))
    .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    .subscribe((todos) => this.userTodoArray = todos);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
  this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
}
```

As `authState()` and `mergeMap()` both return Observables, I think I'm supposed to either

1. Unsubscribe from both of them (as shown above) or
2. Only call one of the `takeUntil()` operators, either from the outer Observable `authState()` or the inner Observable `this.todoService.getUserTodos(user.uid)`.

Which method is correct to make sure all Observables are unsubscribed after the component is destroyed?

Comment: It's number 2: you only need one of the  `takeUntil` operators and it doesn't matter which one you remove.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Any explanation or reference about why #2 is correct?

Comment: Whichever one you use will see the stream complete and the observables unsubscribed. If no one else offers a detailed explanation, I might add an answer later.

Comment: Ok, no prob. Appreciate it!

Comment: I came back to answer this and realised that my comments were wrong. It most likely does matter which you choose to remove, as the behaviours are different.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need both of the `takeUntil` operators. You only need one, but the behaviour will differ depending upon which one you remove.

If you use only the first `takeUntil`, like this:

```
this.fireAuth.authState
  .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
  .mergeMap((user) => this.todoService.getUserTodos(user.uid))
  .subscribe((todos) => this.userTodoArray = todos);
```

When `this.ngUnsubscribe` emits a `next` notification, the `takeUntil` will unsubscribe from the `this.fireAuth.authState` source and will complete. As outlined in the [Observable Contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html), when an observable completes, its subscribers receive a `complete` notification and are automatically unsubscribed.

However, if a `next` notification was emitted from `this.fireAuth.authState` and the observable returned by `getUserTodos` in the `mergeMap` has not yet completed, the `mergeMap` implementation will not unsubscribe from the `getUserTodos` observable. And if the `getUserTodos` observable later emits a `next` notification, the notification will flow through to the `subscribe`.

If you use only the second `takeUntil`, like this:

```
this.fireAuth.authState
  .mergeMap((user) => this.todoService.getUserTodos(user.uid))
  .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
  .subscribe((todos) => this.userTodoArray = todos);
```

When `this.ngUnsubscribe` emits a `next` notification, the `takeUntil` will unsubscribe from the `mergeMap`, which will unsubscribe from `this.fireAuth.authState` and from any returned `getUserTodos` observable.

So, after `this.ngUnsubscribe` emits, no notifications will flow through to the `subscribe`. It's likely that this is the behaviour you are looking for, so you should remove the first `takeUntil` operator.